# Find caller of dynamically added button click's listener

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am adding a list of buttons in code for which I would like to add a click listener.

I am able to add the listener, the issue is I would like to know the button that called the listener.

I have tried the following method, but the passed value to the listener is always the same:

```
foreach (...)
{
    var button = (Button)GameObject.Instantiate(...);

    packIndex++;

    button.onClick.AddListener(() => this.OnButtonClick(packIndex));
}

public void OnButtonClick(int idx)
{
    // idx is always the latest value in the above loop
}
```

**TL;DR**

**How do you find the caller from a button click listener?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it. To store the index, you need to "capture" the packIndex variable by making a copy of `packIndex` inside the for loop. You can see a good explanation of this "closure in a for loop" phenomenon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp).

The following code should work:

```
foreach (...)
{
    var button = (Button)GameObject.Instantiate(...);

    packIndex++;
    var packIndexCopy = packIndex;

    button.onClick.AddListener(() => this.OnButtonClick(packIndexCopy));
}

public void OnButtonClick(int idx)
{
    // idx is always the latest value in the above loop
}
```

Note that the answer by @Nain will also work because in that case the "button" object in `AddListener(() => this.OnButtonClick(button));` refers to a new object that's created each time in the foreach loop, so the compiler will correctly bind the `OnButtonClick` handler to that 'new' copy. In fact, passing the `Button` object in directly feels a little bit cleaner, but that depends on the rest of your code.

If you are unfamiliar with closures (which are really confusing and take a long time to understand!), [this article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) has a good explanation.

P.S. I wrote a small Component to test this, here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/julenka/60762b4f1e1d8d5ad0ac) for it in case it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var button = (Button)GameObject.Instantiate(...);
packIndex++;
button.name = "Button" + packIndex;
button.onClick.AddListener(() => this.OnButtonClick(button));

public void OnButtonClick(Button button)
{
// idx is always the latest value in the above loop
}
```